# Regex to match JWT

Tags: regex

I don't have experience with Regex and I'm asking for your help.

I need a regex to capture the JWT inside the following string:

`"contextJwt": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJIZWxsbyB5b3UiLCJuYW1lIjoiV2h5IGFyZSB5b3UgY2hlY2tpbmcgbXkgdG9rZW4_ICggzaHCsCDNnMqWIM2hwrApIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.yAP0xiTwp6vqIYbLKLVBRv-gTyMvU17rT3H8uErLjHA"`

[Request answer (2363 lines)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2kru.png)

Thanks for your time

Comment: Is the JWT (and the string you shared) arriving as part of a JSON payload?  I.e. could you just decode the JSON and read the value out of the `contextJwt` key?

Comment: It arrives in HTML, so it won't work

Comment: What language are you using to parse the HTML?

Comment: No language, I make the request to the URL and it comes in a string. I need to capture the JWT after "contextJwt"

Comment: What language are you going to use to process the regular expression?  Saying "No language" to me means that you (a human) can look at the text and simply copy and paste the JWT out of it, no coding required.

Comment: I'm using JavaScript, but I don't need to parse the HTML

Comment: I'm confused. Parsing HTML in JavaScript is trivial, it's totally built into the language. Same with JSON. On the other side, using a regular expression makes the problem harder to solve. It's like trying to screw a screw with a shoe, when you already have a screwdriver but you'll need to order the shoe online. I also can't see what the linked picture has to do with JWT.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález when I make a GET request to the chosen endpoint it returns me a full HTML page. I need to do this in order to get a JWT (which comes inside that HTML) to make a request to an API. I know it's hard to understand, but it's the only way possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working with an HTML document as a string and you are using Javascript to run your regular expression, you could do something like the following:

```
const html = '<div>stuff</div>something "contextJwt": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJIZWxsbyB5b3UiLCJuYW1lIjoiV2h5IGFyZSB5b3UgY2hlY2tpbmcgbXkgdG9rZW4_ICggzaHCsCDNnMqWIM2hwrApIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.yAP0xiTwp6vqIYbLKLVBRv-gTyMvU17rT3H8uErLjHA" <div> other stuff</div>';
var regex = /"contextJwt":\s*"(.*)"/;
console.log(html.match(regex)[1]);

/* yields the encoded JWT string:
 eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJIZWxsbyB5b3UiLCJuYW1lIjoiV2h5IGFyZSB5b3UgY2hlY2tpbmcgbXkgdG9rZW4_ICggzaHCsCDNnMqWIM2hwrApIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.yAP0xiTwp6vqIYbLKLVBRv-gTyMvU17rT3H8uErLjHA

*/
```

You can tighten up your match from the simple `(.*)` to the specific characters that are allowed in a valid encoded JWT (per Helio Santo's answer), but since regexes are finicky, I usually start with the simplest solution and only tighten it down when necessary.

What you do with the string that represents an encoded JWT is perhaps another question entirely.

Comment: It worked fine when I combined your expression with Helio's. Thanks guys

Answer (score 26):

I created a regex which might not be the most elegant but it appears to works.

```
(^[A-Za-z0-9-_]*\.[A-Za-z0-9-_]*\.[A-Za-z0-9-_]*$)
```

A more concise version could be also:

```
(^[\w-]*\.[\w-]*\.[\w-]*$)
```

However, I believe that also non-latin characters would be allowed which would be disallowed as JWT.

Comment: instead of `*` (0..n), better use `+` (1..n), otherwise string such as `..` would also match.

Comment: Here's a cleaned up version `/^(?:[\w-]*\.){2}[\w-]*$/` And a tester in case anyone want to try out things like non-latin characters: https://regex101.com/r/0OsWPw/1

Comment: The sequence `9-_` in the regex means *all characters between `9` and `_`* which is incorrect. The characters should be reversed, so that the hyphen comes last `9_-`

Comment: @Buffoonism the character class is parsed from left to right and so `0-9` will take precedence over `9-_` and thus putting the hyphen last is not necessary (though it is still generally a good idea to avoid visual ambiguity)

Answer (score 5):

I'm answering late as this is still one of the top answers on google for `jwt regex` and as is often the case, the accepted answers aren't entirely correct.

The minimum encoded base64url output is two characters, so if you want to avoid matching strings like `a.a.a` (which isn't a JWT) then the following regex is a better alternative:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_-]{2,}(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]{2,}){2}$
```

Answer (score 3):

My simplified version of JWT regex:

`/^[\w-]+\.[\w-]+\.[\w-]+$/`

To test it: https://regex101.com/r/tAGt1D/1

Comment: Simplified, but also matches things that aren't JWTs too. The minimum base64url string is two characters, so a.a.a matches your regex, but isn't a JWT etc.

Answer (score 0):

For the records (error checking omitted for brevity) here is an alternative that doesn't use Regex

```js
const html = `<section>
  <p>Your token is <code>"contextJwt": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJIZWxsbyB5b3UiLCJuYW1lIjoiV2h5IGFyZSB5b3UgY2hlY2tpbmcgbXkgdG9rZW4_ICggzaHCsCDNnMqWIM2hwrApIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.yAP0xiTwp6vqIYbLKLVBRv-gTyMvU17rT3H8uErLjHA"</code>. Have a nice day.</p>
</section>`;
const fragment = document.createElement("div");
fragment.innerHTML = html;
const input = fragment.querySelector("section p code").innerHTML;
const output = JSON.parse("{" + input + "}");
console.log(output.contextJwt);
```

Comment: Hi, it would work if the code was rendered, but I only use it as a string, to get the JWT that comes inside. But thanks!

Comment: `innerHTML` is writable.

Comment: Man what I'm doing is like making a request to "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61802832/regex-to-match-jwt" and using the regex to filter desired info.

Comment: I can't use document. because it isn't rendered in DOM

Comment: @Grampet DOM and rendering are different subjects. I've edited my answer to hopefully illustrate your use case. You can use regular expressions if it's a tool you're more comfortable with, but it's by no means the only way.