# JWT regex for a specific aud

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

When configuring a Cognito Authorizer in API Gateway, a tooltip suggests providing a regex that will pre-validate the audience (aud).

[image: API Gateway Screenshot]

I'm not clear on what the payload will be, so I'm not sure how to write this regex. Is there a sample regex available?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61804243/421195  Or this? https://regex101.com/library/oI0rR9

Comment: No, that finds a JWT within an HTML doc. I'm looking for a regex that will match a particular value of the property "aud" within the JWT itself.